# Approaches to embedded vector images/charts into PDF

Tags: python, linux, pdf-generation

How have people from the Linux world embedded vector images into PDF?

I am attempting to create automated reports from data that I currently render as SVG images. Ideally, I would like to use the same XML in `PostScript`, `PDF` or `DjVu` format. To what degree are those formats able to handle SVG natively?

More broadly, what have people's experiences been? Should I

1. reuse the native SVG XML?
2. rasterise SVGs that have already been created?
3. or use another format?

I'm restricted to formats that are accessible from Ubuntu 10.04 & Python. This will probably exclude me from utilising Adobe Illustrator files.

Comment: Why would you be rasterizing the SVGs? Postscript and PDF, at least, are vector graphics formats.

Comment: Yes, that would be the ideal, I wasn't sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Investigate [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/), its main purpose is to convert XML to PDF.

Upsides (for this project):

- full Apache project (=> reliable)

Downsides (for this project):

- Will need to learn [`XSL-FO`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/)
- Not Python

Answer (score 0):

[Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/index.html) is a nice Java SVG library. It has a utility library called [batik-rasterizer.jar](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html) which can convert SVG into a some useful formats: PDF, TIFF, PNG, and GIF.

You could use Jython to link to this library with python.